# appwidget not responding to user touch

Tags: android

I created a simple appwidget which shows digital clock, and I set a PendingIntent for that clock.(i.e) when the user tap on the textview a dialpad is opened. It works perfectly. But when i opens some application like Car Home and then exit  from the Car Home will makes just a flash my Homescreen. And my widget is now gone to not responding state. I don't know i m going wrong. Past 2 days i m googling for this. Anyone please help.

**java code:**

```
 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    context.startService(new Intent(UpdateService.ACTION_UPDATE));
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    Intent dial = new Intent();
    dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, dial, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Time, pendingIntent);
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews); 
    }
}
```

**AppwidgetProvider:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="150dip" 
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main" />
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:textSize="56sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:shadowColor="#C0000000"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="3.0" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `AppwidgetManager.updatewidget()` in `onupdate`of your `AppWidgetManager` method.